# How to use CreateFile API function for network path?

Tags: winapi, filesystems, network-share

I have come across the CreateFile API for C drive. It is working fine. But when I try to use a network share path it throws an error.

```
private void GetRootHandle()
    {
        string vol = string.Concat(@"\\192.168.1.24\share1");
        _changeJournalRootHandle = PInvokeWin32.CreateFile(vol,
             PInvokeWin32.GENERIC_READ | PInvokeWin32.GENERIC_WRITE,
             PInvokeWin32.FILE_SHARE_READ | PInvokeWin32.FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
             IntPtr.Zero,
             PInvokeWin32.OPEN_EXISTING,
             0,
             IntPtr.Zero);
        if (_changeJournalRootHandle.ToInt32() == PInvokeWin32.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            throw new IOException("CreateFile() returned invalid handle",
                new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }
    }
```

Can any one give me an idea how to use share path for this API function

Comment: Should't you point to a file on that share1? aka \\192.168.1.24\share1\somefile.txt ?

Comment: Hi, Here i need to enumerate all the files under root folder share1 by using the another API function GetFileInformationByHandle not a specific file.

Comment: Isn't [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx) a better start in that case? I don't see how you can enumerate files with the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) api. And why can't you use the System.IO managed classes?

Comment: I need to fetch unique ID of the specific file or folder that is available only in BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION ..pls go through the links http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363788(VS.85).aspx

Comment: also this one http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c1550294-d121-4511-ac32-31551497f64e

Comment: What is the error code you are getting?

Comment: I am getting Access is denied exception

Answer (score 2):

> I am getting Access is denied exception

That's because it is not a file.  Get ahead by *not* using CreateFile(), it just isn't necessary.  Use the regular .NET classes, like DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles() to enumerate files, FileStream to open them.  Use the FileStream.SafeFileHandle property if you need to pinvoke GetFileInformationByHandle().

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer...  FileStream.SafeFileHandle worked out for me...I am very happy to see people like you..pls continue your service forever.

Comment: Hi, Do you have any idea to get absolute path(C:\share) from UNC path(\\192.168.1.124\share)?

Comment: Running your program on the server machine itself will be easier.  But surely not what you want.

Comment: I am running the program from one server(devServer) and trying to get file infromation from remote server (192.168.1.124)

Answer (score 1):

The access denied error is caused because you do not have permissions to open the file or folder with the privileges you have requested.  In this case, read and write.  [GetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not require write privileges.  You should remove `PInvokeWin32.GENERIC_WRITE` from the `desiredAccess` (2nd) parameter.

The MSDN docs for [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say you can pass in 0 to the `desiredAccess` parameter and use the handle in `GetFileInformationByHandle`.

> The dwDesiredAccess parameter can be zero, allowing the application to query file attributes without accessing the file if the application is running with adequate security settings. This is useful to test for the existence of a file without opening it for read and/or write access, or to obtain other statistics about the file or directory. See Obtaining and Setting File Information and GetFileInformationByHandle.

However, you will probably be better served by the [Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.aspx) class in C# for retrieving directory information.